# flask app not handling bad input, not showing error msg in postman

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask app and testing it in python. i send 2 files and if either not given - it should give me json error msg "need 2 files"

```
@app.route('/compare_voices', methods = ['POST'])
def compare_voices():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file1 = request.files["file1"]
        file2 = request.files["file2"]

        if file1 == None or file2 == None:
            return jsonify({'response':"need 2 files!"}) #this should trigger
        else:
            answer = 'ok'
            return jsonify({'response': answer})
```

Instead it crashes like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'file1' // Werkzeug Debugger</title>
```

but i want this case to be handled and just see error msg "need 2 files"

Comment: There are 2 errors in this code, the sort answer is that when `file2 = request.files["file2"]` doesn't exist in the params, it is not `None`, it crashes, add `try:... except:...` before and after `file1 = ... file2 =...` and the exception should use the custom error

Comment: @Missilexent thx will do now

Comment: @Missilexent hmm it gives <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ApiError: {'result': 'err', 'errcode': 'ERR001', 'errtext': 'need 2 files!'} // Werkzeug Debugger</title>

Comment: @Missilexent it still shows the error, but the status in the upper right corner is "500 server error"

Comment: it shows the right error msg, but it still crashes with right error msg

Comment: It should return response code 200OK?

Comment: @Missilexent, yes this is what expected, but it goes with 500 internal server error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212296/discussion-between-missilexent-and-erjan).

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are 2 issues in this code, The errors are:
1. One of the parameters files doesn't exist
2. One of the files are empty (param exist, but no file was selected, should be handled on front end actually)

```
@app.route('/comp', methods = ['POST'])
def compare_voices():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:                    
            file1 = request.files["file1"]
            file2 = request.files["file2"]
        except:
            return jsonify({'response':"need 2 files!"})

        if file1.filename == '' or file2.filename == '': 
            answer = "need 2 files!"                    
        else:                                           
            answer = 'ok'

        return jsonify({'response': answer})
```

This should fix it, taking care on the 2 cases